# JavaScript: Solving an algorithmic problem

Tags: javascript

Today I was working on a problem, which states as follows:

## Problem:

- **INPUT**:  `[{..}, {..}, ..]` Array of objects;
- Each object is has `{"id": required, "children": []}`
- The objects has **parent-child relation** based on `"id" and "children"` props
- **OUTPUT**: `[{..}, {..}, ..]` Array in a tree (hierarchy) order :**multi-level**.

---

### Input:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Earth",
    "children": [2, 3]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Asia",
    "children": []
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Europe",
    "children": [4]
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Germany",
    "children": [5]
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Hamburg",
    "children": []
}]
```

---

### OutPut

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Earth",
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Asia",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Europe",
        "children": [{
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Germany",
            "children": [{
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Hamburg",
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

## My approach

I decided to solve this by iterating through each element in the array and ***recursively*** find and append objects to **`children`** of each element.

> So just to start with, I decided to have only **First level children** appended their respective parents. And my code is following.

```js
var posts = [{"id":1,"name":"Earth","children":[2,3]},{"id":2,"name":"Asia","children":[]},{"id":3,"name":"Europe","children":[4]},{"id":4,"name":"Germany","children":[5]},{"id":5,"name":"Hamburg","children":[]}]

function getElementById (id, posts) {
 for(var i =0; i< posts.length; i++){
  if(posts[i].id === id){
   var found = posts[i];
///// FUN here -> //// posts.splice(i, 1);
   return found;
  }
 }
} 

function refactorChildren(element, posts) {
  if(!element.children || element.children.length === 0) {
    return element;
  }
  
  var children = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++){
    var childElement = getElementById(element.children[i], posts);    
    children.push(childElement);
  }
  element.children = children;
  
  return element;
}

function iterate(posts) {
  var newPosts = [];
  var des = [...posts]
  for(var i = 0; i < des.length; i++){
    var childedElement = refactorChildren(des[i], des);
     newPosts.push(childedElement);
  }
  
  return newPosts;
}


var filtered = iterate(posts);
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered))
```

> Surprisingly above code **Solves the ACTUAL PROBLEM** (except a lil bit of more work)

**My Expected Result should be the following:** Array of objects with only **First level children**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Earth",
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Asia",
        "children": []
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Europe",
        "children": [4]
    }]
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Germany",
    "children": [{
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Hamburg",
        "children": []
    }]
}]
```

And I do get the above result if I uncomment the `///// FUN here -> ////` line. Which is erasing the iterating object on the go.

So my problem is

I want to know - **HOW DID?** All the objects got appended correctly to their respective Parent objects by that code? My next step was to add a recursion call to the function `refactorChildren(with-childElement)`.

AND

How did, just by adding `posts.splice(i, 1);` got me MY expected result from the code?

Please help me understand, I just cant go ahead without knowing "HOW".

Thanks

Comment: This doesnt work if a child is in the array before its parent.

Comment: @Jonas I just tried, it still works works https://jsfiddle.net/t3gy14zu/ 
notice the "Earth" it has its child and its child has its child

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You wrote the code but don't understand it? What part confuses you exactly?

Comment: @Chipster, The code i wrote doesnt yields expected result.

Comment: Ah you don't understand why that one line of code fixed it?

Comment: Yes exactly! Also I need to know how appending only 1st level child , recursively appends the respective children to their parents

Answer (score 1):

While traversing the objects, you recursively call a function on all its chilfren and remove the objects from the array:

```
 [
   { id: 1, children: [2], }, // < iterator
   { id: 2, children: [] }, // < gets spliced out recursively
 ]
```

If a child is in the array before its parent however, this won't work as you copy the child into another array before the parent gets visited.

Comment: Sorry but I think its not the case I tried putting child before the parent in this example https://jsfiddle.net/t3gy14zu/ but it still works somehow!

Comment: @SiddharthaChowdhury Once you put 'Asia' before the 'Earth' you can see the difference.

Comment: Guys I only care about the values in "Earth". Whose value is still the same no matter how you change the order. I am not concerned about the order or rest of the indexes. My problem is something else - I wanted to know how the multilevel append happening without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are interested in a different approach with only a single loop for getting the parent elements and their children.

This works for unsorted data, too.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: "Earth", children: [2, 3] }, { id: 2, name: "Asia", children: [] }, { id: 3, name: "Europe", children: [4] }, { id: 4, name: "Germany", children: [5] }, { id: 5, name: "Hamburg", children: [] }],
    tree = function (array) {
        var r = {},
            children = new Set,
            result = [];

        array.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(
                r[o.id] = r[o.id] || {},
                o,
                { children: o.children.map(id => (children.add(id), r[id] = r[id] || {})) }
            );
        });
        return Object.values(r).filter(({ id }) => !children.has(id));
    }(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for another solution, [+1] I have solved the above problem, your code is simpler. But I just wanted to know how is the above happening